# Undefined offset: 1 (summernote in laravel) when update

Tags: laravel, updates, summernote

i have an update function, i want to update the content using summernote, but issue an Undefined offset error: 1 on line 67 .. please help me guys.
Thank you guys

```
foreach ($images as $k => $img) {
            $data = $img->getattribute('src');
            list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);// line 67
            list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);
            $data = base64_decode($data);
            $image_name= time().$k.'.png';
            $path = public_path('/'. $image_name);
            file_put_contents($path, $data);
            $img->removeattribute('src');
            $img->setattribute('src','/'.$image_name);
        }
```

Comment: Please also provide the contents of $images :)

Comment: this guys
$content = $request->body;
        $dom = new \DomDocument();
        $dom->loadHtml($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
        $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

Comment: Thank you for the addition, but i actually meant the **actual** contents of $images when you execute the code and get the error (or an example of this)

Comment: this...$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

Comment: That is the **code** for the $images array, i mean an example like: ["keyName"=>"imageName"] of the **actual** data which is used in the for loop (you can retrieve this with `var_dump($images);`)

Comment: have you found the solution yet ? Having same problem.